Are there any ways to wake up Linux laptops with the closed lid from suspend?
Any suggestions for this question will be fairly appreciated.
We are trying to make an 'update date': scheduled wake-up and some commands (such as apt update && apt dist-upgrade) execution. There are no problems to wake up desktop machines, we could trigger wake-up by cron task (executed every hour) to execute rtcwake -m no -l -t [datetime] and it leads machines to wake up at [datetime].
The problem is laptops. If we send rtcwake -m no -l -t [datetime] and at [datetime] the laptop lid is closed, it leads laptop to skip wakeup at scheduled time. If the lid is opened, there are no problems at all. So, we are trying to make the laptop lid action to be ignored (I suppose, the power manager is infinitely listening for laptop lid state, so if it's closed, the power manager declines all wake-up requests or leads laptop to sleep immediately after wake-up).
The distributives we use is Astra Linux 1.7.[4-5][.uu1]. There is a package called fly-admin-power to manage power settings (including the laptop lid action), it has no man page or any documentation. The only thing this package does, is running the GUI for powerdevilglobalconfig and powerdeviluserconfig modules.
So, the question is "Are there any config files that we could change to ignore the laptop lid state?" Which power manager we should configure to avoid conflicts? We want to use config files to avoid setting this value manually for new laptops or old ones (we have about 100 laptops, it's kinda difficult task). There is no problem to distribute the config file around all the laptops using ALDPro. But we haven't found any config files responsible for that.
We've tried to change /etc/systemd/logind.conf, but it leads to some critical conflicts: after rebooting the machine, there is no way to load a desktop after logging in, even if we didn't do anything with the laptop lid. Reverting changes is helpful.
Also, we've tried to modify some files at ~/.config, but it has no effect. Also, ignoreLid parameter at /etc/UPower/UPower.conf is useless.
Also, we would like to avoid some extra software to manage the laptop lid action (the Astra Linux documentation states, that it may lead to conflicts between power managers).
Note: Machines has no 'Wake on LAN' function. Also, the 'Turning on with AC connected' option in BIOS is not presented.

@John, we thought about it. The problem is unpredictable machine working time: it could work for hours, or for few minutes. Sometimes we have to update the distibutive, so it may lead to kernel/distro damage, if the laptop is turned off during the update.

If we (as system admins, not users) have to power on each machine to update, we come to the issue we want to avoid: powering on 100+ machines once a month.

@John – Plenty of people use their laptops with the lid closed and an external monitor attached. I had a Thinkpad run pretty much continuously for ten years, never suspending it when the lid was closed (no monitor was connected). Any system that overheats when the lid is closed but not when the lid is opened is flawed.
